# Using ORMLite to Save PostgreSQL Custom Enumerated Datatypes

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite

This might be a silly question, because the problem at hand is rather rudimentary and I'm more than sure the answer is probable quite simple. Nonetheless, I was not able to find a comprehensive solution to my problem even after hours of digging around.

I'm using ORMLite with a PostgreSQL database with Java. As I'm trying to persist an object to a mapped table, the self defined Postgres enum datatypes seem to be giving me headache.

Here's an example of a the situation:

The Java class is annotated as follows:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_STRING)
    private CustomerType customerType;
...
```

The enumeration is defined as follows:

```
public enum CustomerType{
    company, private, unknown
}
```

The Postgres datatype ("customertype") is defined as an enumerated type (in the pg_enum & pg_type tables) with the following values:

```
"company"
"private"
"unknown"
```

...and the column itself is defined be of this type:

```
ALTER TABLE public.customer ADD COLUMN type customertype;
```

When I try to insert a new row using ORMLite to the customer table, I'm getting the following exception, which tells me that the mapping is some what screwed up and ORMLite seems to be handling the value incorrectly as a varchar, instead of the custom defined enum type:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "type" is of type customertype but expression is of type character varying
```

I'm just a little baffled on how to correctly map the enumerated types. I've tried most of the different datatypes for the database field definitions and other persisting rules without luck.

As it might be obvious, I'm rather new to ORMLite, so all help is more than appreciated!

Comment: In general ORMs play poorly with custom database types. You might have some luck by setting the stringtype to unspecified; append `stringtype=unspecified` to your JDBC parameters.

Comment: As matter of fact that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general ORMs play poorly with custom database types.

You might have some luck by setting the stringtype to unspecified; append `stringtype=unspecified` to your JDBC parameters. This tells PgJDBC to send parameters of type `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` as `unknown` instead of the default of `text`. PostgreSQL won't implicitly cast from `text` to an enum, but it *will* from an unknown-typed literal to an enum.

In my opinion PostgreSQL is being too strict with its casting here, but I haven't had much luck convincing the relevant people on pgsql-hackers of that yet.